# How to debug NoSuchMethodError exception ? org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.addAnnotatedClass(Ljava/lang/Class;)

Tags: eclipse, hibernate, maven, exception, servlets

When I try to initialize a Hibernate 4 SessionFactory in a servlet:

```
Configuration config;
ServiceRegistry registry;
SessionFactory factory;
config = new Configuration();
config = config.addAnnotatedClass(Star.class); // <-- Exception here.
```

I get an exception:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [hu.adamsan.store.TestHibernate] in context with path [/TestProject] threw exception [Servlet execution threw an exception] with root cause
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.addAnnotatedClass(Ljava/lang/Class;)Lorg/hibernate/cfg/Configuration;
at hu.adamsan.store.TestHibernate.doGet(TestHibernate.java:75)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
at
```

When I looked up in Google, I could not find a solution, but similar errors were present when there was a mismatch with the hibernate version. I've made a similar project, with the exact same maven dependencies, with the same code initializing hibernate in a doGet method, and it worked.

maven dependencies:

```
mysql-connector-java 5.1.26
hibernate-core 4.2.6.Final
hibernate-validator 5.0.1.Final
commons-beanutils 1.8.3
commons-collections 3.2.1
log4j 1.2.17
slf4j-api 1.7.5
```

Does anyone have an idea, what could be wrong?
Can someone offer general advice, how to handle, debug such obscure errors?

Answer (score 2):

When you get a `NoSuchMethodError` in external libraries, it is usually due to having multiple versions of the same dependency on the classpath. This might be due to a transitive dependency, so detecting it through just looking at the dependency in the `pom.xml` of your project is not enough. If you do a `mvn dependency:tree`, it will list all transitive dependencies as well, so look for multiple versions of the same dependency.

It might also be that the same class is implemented is multiple dependencies, so google it to find out which jars contain it. http://www.jarfinder.com/index.php/java/info/org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration

Comment: Thanks. In the meantime, I've figured out. Earlier I've tried hibernate 3, I've changed in the pom file to hibernate 4, and I thought, that it would take care of the jar files. But it didnt. When I looked up the folder what getServletContext().getRealPath() gives, inside WEB-INF\lib there were the older versions of the jars.

Comment: Is it normal for maven to not do this, even after cleanup/rebuilding the project? Do I really have to manually delete the jars from there? I thought the point of maven would be to automate these things.
I'm using the maven that's coming with eclipse jee version built in. I assume, that the dependency:tree should give a similar output to the eclipse pom.xml/dependency hierarchy tab. Here I could not se the older versions of jars.
So, basically, how can I make automate the handling of these dependency jars?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand 100%, but IDEs have a mechanism for adding stuff to classpath (then it's outside of maven). So if this happened when running from the IDE, it might that there was a depedency conflict between a maven dependency and one added to classpath in Eclipse only..